# Data binding to an array collection not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm trying to make a CheckBox element visible based on whether a particular string exists in this bindable array collection I have, but it doesn't seem to work. I'd really appreciate it if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

In my actionscript code, I have

```
[Bindable]private var dataTypesUsed:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

and in my flex code, I have

```
<s:CheckBox selected="true" label="test" id="testBox" visible="{dataTypesUsed.contains('Target')}" includeInLayout="{dataTypesUsed.contains('Target')}"/>
```

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such thing as a `contains()` method on `ArrayCollection`

Comment: There is, it's derived from `ListCollectionView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `contains()` method of `ArrayCollection` is not [Bindable]. In MXML curly brace expressions, everything in the chain of properties must be [Bindable].

Normally, the Flex compiler will warn you  when one of the properties in a curly brace expression is not [Bindable]. The warning is not generated when one of the properties is a function, by design I presume, as it can be a useful shortcut.

Functions can be marked as [Bindable]. As long as somewhere in the class that defines the function the "binding" event is dispatched.  Take a look at the source code for `ListCollectionView` -- this is the class that actually defines the `contains()` method.

You'll see that the `contains()` method is not marked as [Bindable], and for contrast that the `getItemAt()` method is.

You can solve your problem a few different ways. Here's one that dispatches a custom binding event:

```
[Bindable("dataTypesUsedChanged")]
private var dataTypesUsed:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

private function someMethodThatUpdatesTheCollection():void
{
    dataTypesUsed.addItem("foo");
    // addItem will make the collection dispatch CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE
    dispatchEvent(new Event("dataTypesUsedChanged")

}

<s:CheckBox visible={dataTypesUsed.contains('foo')} />
```

The difference is that when you don't specify the event name in the [Bindable] metadata, Flex uses the default "propertyChanged" event.

In your scenario, nothing was dispatching the "propertyChange" event to trigger binding (b/c the property literally did not change). In addition, the "collectionChange" event dispatched by the collection was not being used b/c the `contains()` method isn't marked as [Bindable].

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Stupid question, but isn't the contains method still not bound to any event? So would the MXML curly braces work now? (Or does either the contains method, or the collection object have to be bound to an event that actually occurs, for it to work?). Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Correct, the contains() method isn't Bound to anything. My example above only binds to the dataTypesUsed variable. The reason my example works is because it dispatches the event saying something has changed (causing the curly brace expression to be evaluated). In your original example so event was being generated to trigger the binding